# th:field (SpringBoot + ThymeLeaf) question

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to build a very lightweight app, and I do not understand why it does not work. Can someone enlight me ?

My model could not be more simple :

```
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import lombok.Data;
@Data
public class Credentials {  private String ident; }
```

Here is my controller :

```
    @GetMapping("/") 
    public String index(Model model) {
        logger.info(loggingMsgFactory.get("ui.index"));
        //getHeaderData(model);
        Credentials credential = new Credentials();
        model.addAttribute("credential", credential);
        return "index"; 
    }
```

And here is my HTML :

```
<body>
 <div th:replace="~{fragments/header :: header}"></div>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/bind}" method="post" th:object="${credential}">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{ident}" /></p>
    </form> 
<div th:replace="~{fragments/footer :: footer}"></div>
</body>
```

The problem comes when I try to run the app :

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 11, col 32)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
```

This is due to the the th:field statement, but I do not understand why.

Comment: Seems correct, what does the rest of the stack trace say?

Comment: Thanks for replying. In fact, it does not find getters and setters for the object (th:field). I understood that Lombok was in charge of this...